# Vector can not be imported in JNI

Tags: android, c++, c, android-ndk, java-native-interface

in Java code:

```
System.loadLibrary("twolib-second");

int  z = add(1, 2);

public native int add(int  x, int  y);
```

first.cpp:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus extern "C" {
#endif


using namespace std;


int first(int  x, int  y) {
    return x*10 + y; }

#ifdef __cplusplus }
#endif
```

second.c:

> ```
> //THIS IS THE source of trouble :)
> //without the include of vector works just fine
> //but after adding the include for vector code can't be compiled
> #include <vector>
> ```

```
#include <jni.h>

jint
Java_com_example_jniexample_MainActivity_add( JNIEnv*  env,
                                      jobject  this,
                                      jint     x,
                                      jint     y )
{
    return first(x, y);
}
```

Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)

# first lib, which will be built statically
#
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := libtwolib-first
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := first.cpp

include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)

# second lib, which will depend on and include the first one
#
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := libtwolib-second
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := second.c

LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := libtwolib-first

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

I keep getting this error:

> from jni/second.c:20: /home/username/dev/ndk/android-ndk-r9/sources/cxx-stl/stlport/stlport/stl/_relops_cont.h:6:1:
>   error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '**attribute**' before '<'
>   token
>   /home/username/dev/ndk/android-ndk-r9/sources/cxx-stl/stlport/stlport/stl/_relops_cont.h:14:1:
>   error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '**attribute**' before '<'
>   token
>   /home/username/dev/ndk/android-ndk-r9/sources/cxx-stl/stlport/stlport/stl/_relops_cont.h:21:1:
>   error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '**attribute**' before '<'
>   token
>   /home/username/dev/ndk/android-ndk-r9/sources/cxx-stl/stlport/stlport/stl/_relops_cont.h:21:1:
>   error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '**attribute**' before '<'
>   token
>   /home/username/dev/ndk/android-ndk-r9/sources/cxx-stl/stlport/stlport/stl/_relops_cont.h:21:1:
>   error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '**attribute**' before '<'
>   token
>   /home/username/dev/ndk/android-ndk-r9/sources/cxx-stl/stlport/stlport/stl/_relops_cont.h:21:1:
>   error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '**attribute**' before '<'
>   token
>   /home/username/dev/ndk/android-ndk-r9/sources/cxx-stl/stlport/stlport/stl/_relops_cont.h:24:1:
>   error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '**attribute**' before '<'
>   token In file included from
>   /home/username/dev/ndk/android-ndk-r9/sources/cxx-stl/stlport/stlport/vector:37:0,
>                    from jni/second.c:20: /home/username/dev/ndk/android-ndk-r9/sources/cxx-stl/stlport/stlport/stl/_vector.h:752:10:
>   error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '**attribute**' before '<'
>   token
>   /home/username/dev/ndk/android-ndk-r9/sources/cxx-stl/stlport/stlport/stl/_vector.h:760:10:
>   error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '**attribute**' before '<'
>   token

in Application.mk

> APP_STL := stlport_static

Comment: vector is C++ and you are trying to use in it C code?

Comment: I strongly recommemd you to read all of the Ndk example projects with special attention to Android makefiles.  You will see how to use STL there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you use the default C++ runtime, which does not support the Standard Library.

See the file docs/CPLUSPLUS-SUPPORT.html in your ndk installation folder for the whole information.

To be able to use (and thus, include without error) `vector`, you need to define `APP_STL` in your Application.mk
You can use strlport or gnustl to enable the standard library in native Android development, by adding something like that:

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static
```

Another issue: You try to include `vector` in a C file, so it doesn't work.

Comment: I made an update in my question. I already have Application.mk file with APP_STL := gnustl_static

Comment: Updated my answer for another problem I saw.

Comment: It seems to be a trouble to have vector in jni code. So my question is how can i get result from c++ function that returns vector or list<strings>... any guidelines , tnx

Comment: You said you put the vector include in second.c, so it's C code and won't compile. I use vector everyday in C++ on android.

Comment: All I want to ask is how can I use vector class in jni or list<string> ... Or how can I map from c++ to jni for these kind of data structures. I have c++ function that returns vector and list<string> so I want to use them in my jni code. My jni code is written in second.c file

Comment: That's not the scope of the question you posted. I suggest you try to rename second.c to second.cpp, declare all JNIEXPORT as `extern "C"` and try again if it works. Then you can ask another question with a specific case, as there is no direct relation between C++ objects and Java objects, we'll have to do a special case depending on your needs.